# linux sorting of lists using the last parts using sort command

Tags: command-line, sort

how do I sort lists like the one below using `sort` or any related commands?

```
12.ale.panal.sel.blr.teta.hf.ew.rr.lwq.ors.2018
34.ev.we.ars.lmn.2017
5.lam.bere.meto.belagn.hede.we.e.2020
54.arad.met.kal.sil.tek.br.yz.2005
```

I want to sort them according to the last word which is the year chronologically?

N.B basically something like `sort -t. -k-1` although `-1` is not allowed. Any command just to address the last part?

Comment: the third word meaning the word after 3 dots from the start of the line

Comment: not really because they are not columns rather just words and numbers just connected with dots

Comment: You just have to tell sort that your field separator is the dot. Check the `-t` flag.

Comment: You know, one of the conditions of asking here is to do some research first. Sometimes people will give you an answer, but usually you have to show that you've tried. The command `sort` sorts based on fields (see the answer linked above). By default the field separator is whitespace, with `-t.` the field separator will be a dot. You' most likely can pick it up from there.

Comment: Yes, using both flags.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clear

Answer (score 1):

With a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

```bsh
... | awk -F. -v OFS=. '{print $NF, $0}' | sort -t. -n -k1,1 | cut -d. -f2-
```

where `...` is whatever command you use to produce the list.